# How to justify side-by-side buttons to centre with spacing between them?

Tags: react-native

[My page currently!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdsUO.png)
Hi guys, I made these 2 buttons and I want them to be justified to the center, have rounded edges as well as have some spacing between them. This is my code currently:

```
export default class SortingComponent extends Component {



render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <Text style = {styles.heading}>
                    Find Clinics By:
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection:"row" }}>
                <View style = {styles.buttonStyle}>
                    <Button 
                        title="Total Time"
                        onPress = {() => console.log("Sort by Total Time")}
                    >Total Time</Button>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.buttonStyle}>
                    <Button
                        title="Travel Time"
                        onPress = {() => console.log("Sort by Travel Time")}
                    >Travel Time</Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  }
});
```

Comment: justify-content : 'space-evenly' use this for your container of the buttons. In your it's ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content : 'space-evenly'` in view like

```
<View style={{ flexDirection:"row", justify-content : 'space-evenly'}}>
   .....
</View>
```